# Можно ли ускорить время запроса на сервер на Java?

Tags: java, json

Мне нужно сделать 700 запросов на различные json.

К примеру, если я делаю один из таких запросов, то получение ответа занимает 12 секунд. Соотвественно  на все 700 запросов уйдет около 2 часов.

Я использовал библиотеки HtmlUnit(net.sourceforge.htmlunit
) и rest-assured(com.jayway.restassured)

Пример кода на HtmlUnit  на два запроса:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Page page = client.getPage("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=01.12.2014");
    WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();

    Page page2 = client.getPage("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=02.12.2014");
    WebResponse response2 = page2.getWebResponse();

    System.out.println(response.getContentAsString());
    System.out.println(response2.getContentAsString());
```

Пример кода на rest-assured на два запроса:

```
String sURL ="https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json";
    Map<String, String> queryParms= new HashMap<>();
    queryParms.put("date", String.valueOf("01.12.2014"));
    Response response =  RestAssured.expect().statusCode(200).given()
            .queryParameters(queryParms)
            .log().all()
            .when()
            .get(sURL)
            .then().assertThat()
            .log().all()
            .extract().response();
    System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());

    String sURL ="https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json";
    queryParms.put("date", String.valueOf("02.12.2014"));
    Response response =  RestAssured.expect().statusCode(200).given()
            .queryParameters(queryParms)
            .log().all()
            .when()
            .get(sURL)
            .then().assertThat()
            .log().all()
            .extract().response();
    System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
```

С другой стороны, если я делаю запрос через браузер на те же адреса, к примеру через Chrome, то запрос происходит мгновенно.

Как на Java делать такие же быстрые запросы?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, можно распараллелить отправку запросов, используя асинхронный [`AsyncHttpClient`](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

Про саму настройку [пула подключений читать тут](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/wiki/Connection-pooling).

Comment: WebClient - асинхронный хттп клиент.

Comment: @aleshka-batman тогда почему он в примере используется синхронно?

Comment: пардон, это видать другая библиотека. Я этот имел ввиду https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.html#method.summary